# Enumeration .Except from jQuery Parameter

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to create a function that takes in a string that corresponds to an item within an enum. The following syntax works fine but I want to be able to change the `ChannelType.EndUser` to use the parameter passed into the function instead, is this possible?
Here is my function:

```
  function closeEdit(channel){
             @{

                  var channels = Enum.GetValues(typeof(ChannelType))
                    .Cast<ChannelType>()
                    .Except(new ChannelType[] {ChannelType.EndUser});

                  }
                  @foreach (ChannelType channeltype in channels)
        {
        @:var buttonname = "#Cancel_" + '@(channeltype.ToString())' + "_Update";
        @:if(buttonname != 'Cancel_EndUser_Update'){

        @:$(buttonname).click();}
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wouldn't be able to do that in your actual C# code, you'd have to take off that `Except`, then in your `foreach`, make sure the `ChannelType` isn't the passed in item.

Something like this:

```
 function closeEdit(channel){
     @{
         var channels = Enum.GetValues(typeof(ChannelType))
             .Cast<ChannelType>()
      }
      @foreach (ChannelType channeltype in channels)
      {
          @:var buttonname = "#Cancel_" + '@(channeltype.ToString())' + "_Update";
          @:if(buttonname != 'Cancel_EndUser_Update' && '@(channelType.ToString())' != channel){

          @:$(buttonname).click();}
      }
 }
```

Comment: That's similar to the way I had it before, I thought maybe there was a way to mix the parameter with the LINQ query, but alas, there doesn't seem to be. Thank you for your assistance :)

Comment: @MichaelCampbell Nah unfortunately there's no way to do that. If this was the correct answer, click the tick next to it :). Welcome to SO!